# Files.newInputStream() inconsequential behaviour when the target Path is a directory?

Tags: java, java.nio.file

**NOTE: Please run the exact code below; no adaptations of it, in particular, do not use `File`, as this bug is tied to the new `java.nio.file` API**

OK, this is not really a "question which is in need of an answer" but rather a call for witnesses...

Scenario:

- have a directory on your OS, whatever it is, which you know you have privileges to access -- in Unix parlance, you have at least read access to it (which means you can list the entries in it); in the code below, it is supposed that the path represented by `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")` fits the bill;
- have a **Oracle JDK, or OpenJDK, 7+ installed**; so that you have `java.nio.file` at your disposal.

Now, what the code below does is pretty simple: it tries to [open a new `InputStream` on this directory using `Files.newInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newInputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-). Code (also available [here](https://gist.github.com/fge/1a245934760974d559ea); added comments mine):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public final class Main
{
    public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException
    {
        final Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
        try (
            final InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(path); // FAIL_OPEN
        ) {
            final byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(buf)) != -1) // FAIL_READ
                System.out.printf("%d bytes read\n", bytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```

OK, now when you run that code, this is what happens for the following JRE/OS combinations:

- Linux x86_64, Oracle JDK 1.8.0_25: `IOException (is a directory)` at `FAIL_READ`;
- Linux x86_64, Oracle JDK 1.7.0_72: `IOException (is a directory)` at `FAIL_READ`;
- Mac OS X x86_64, Oracle JDK 1.8.0_25: `IOException (is a directory)` at `FAIL_READ`;
- Windows 7, Oracle JDK 1.8.0_25: `AccessDeniedException` at `FAIL_OPEN` (!!).

Honestly, I don't know what to do with that piece of code. As I said in the introduction, I am looking for witnesses here. I will certainly open a bug to OpenJDK about this, it seems pretty serious. I also mailed the nio-dev mailing list about this problem.

Well, as to a question I'd have one: what about a `IsDirectoryException` in the JDK (inheriting `FileSystemException`)? I have actually defined it in [one of my projects](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-base) to account for such a problem. I am not sure why this problem was not considered by the "Java guys"...

Comment: Creating a new `FileInputStream` directly seems (I've only tried on mac) to catch the fact that it is a directory right away.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis this seems to contradict the other testimony I have on Mac OS X; care to share the exact source and stack trace (in particular, the line where it says that the path "is a directory")?

Comment: Just `final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path.toFile())` produces `Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/folders/7z/ndxp48z14636frp1_rrr8x_8002l2v/T (Is a directory)
`. Sorry for code in comments.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis this is not the code that I run at all! Please use the exact code; no `File`, please. `File` has its own problems

Comment: No, I get the same results as you when I run your code. I'm just saying using `FileInputStream` would seemingly detect the directory problem earlier.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't care about `FileInputStream` ;) I want to know the results specifically with classes of `java.nio.file`. I have dropped `File` usage for a while now

Answer (score 1):

My observations (sorry, no other systems around here atm, later I might add ARM):

- JDK 1.8.0_25, Linux x86_64: `java.io.IOException: Is a directory` at `// FAIL_READ`.

I agree that this behavior is unexpected, it should not be possible to create an InputStream from a directory in the first place. *I suggest you file this as a bug.* Even if `Files.newInputStream` doesn't state it explicitly, the behavior is inconsistent with the rest of the API.

Comment: "I suggest you file this as a bug" <-- well, I'm on the nio-dev OpenJDK mailing list and reported this there; there's a patchset which is ready to go but I don't know when it will make it however.